# Type parameter constraints for the liskov principle in C#.NET

Tags: c#, generics, constraints, liskov-substitution-principle

I try to create a generic interface that inherits the System.ICloneable interface but where the returntype of the Clone()-method is T. Of course the T-type needs constraints to be sure it's an inheritance of the System.Object-class but the following code is not working.

```
public interface ICloneable<T> : System.ICloneable where T : object {

   T Clone ();

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also the following constraints don't work:

1. where T : System.Object
2. where T : class

how can I use the Liskov-principle in this case that says that you can narrow your return type, to solve this problem?

P.S.: Sorry for my English, if i made mistakes. I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: No need to excuse for your English, it's just fine.

Comment: Incidentally, I would suggest that you mark the type T as covariant (put the word "out" before it) and also either add a read-only property "T self", or else define an interface ISelf<T> with a read-only property "T self".   Note that T should not be constrained to be ICloneable<T> nor ISelf<T>.  If you do this, one can have classes Foo and DerivedFoo with no public clone method, and classes CloneableFoo and CloneableDerivedFoo which derive from those, and accept any cloneable derivative of Foo as an ICloneable<Foo>, even though such cloneable derivatives share no common base class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you need a constraint at all? Everything inherits from `object`...

Without the constraint your code should work but you'll need to implement both `Clone` methods in the same way as `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerable<T>` work - .NET doesn't have covariant return types. You should also then specify that your `Clone` method is hiding the one in `ICloneable`:

```
public interface ICloneable<T> : ICloneable
{
    new T Clone();
}
```

Note that the current `ICloneable` interface is somewhat deprecated - because it gives no indication of the depth of cloning, it's not terribly useful in most cases.

Do you really need to extend the non-generic type at all? Do you expect users to want to use the non-generic interface as well as your generic one?

Comment: I want an interface so i need to write the Clone()-method only one time. So without rewriting it for System.ICloneable.Clone(). And i only need to implement the ICloneable<T>-interface. Without writing methods that are hidden by that method.

Comment: In that case I'd remove any reference to the non-generic interface, and without the constraint you should be fine.